# Java finding place in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, minimum

So I have to find the minimum in an array in Java, but with that I have to print out the corresponding names that go with the minimum in another parallel array. Inside my for loop where I find the minimum, I have a variable place that I set equal to my counter variable from the for loop when the minimum is changed. But every time I print out the name, it prints out the first name in the array instead of the name in the place holder.

```
public double getMinimum(double[] money)
{
    double lowest = money[0];

    for (int p = 0; p < money.length; p++)
    {
        if (money[p] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = money[p];
            place = p;
        }
    }

    return lowest;
}
```

Theres the for loop within my programmer-defined class that finds the minimum.

```
public String getFirstNameMin(String[] firstName)
{
    String minFirstName;          
    minFirstName = firstName[place];          
    return minFirstName;
}
```

This is the code I'm using to figure out the first name from the first names array at that place. What am I doing wrong? I'm kinda new to Java, but I did all this array stuff in C++ before, so idk if I am missing something very simple, or its different in Java.

Comment: not enough code to assert a/ the identity of `place` b/ the sequence of execution. Post some data too.

Comment: Where do you define `place`? What does you main-method look like?

Answer (score 1):

I would say try making a separate class for this that contains the user and the money:

```
public class User {

    private double money;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;

    //getters/setters/constructors

}
```

Then from there you can simply compare the accounts:

```
public User getMinimum(User[] users) {

    if (users.length <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    User lowest = users[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].getMoney() < lowest.getMoney()) {
            lowest = users[i];
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public int getMinIndex(double[] money)
{
    double min = money[0];
    int minIndex = 0;

    for (int p = 0; p < money.length; p++)
    {
        if (money[p] < min)
        {
            min = money[p];
            minIndex = p;
        }
    }

    return minIndex;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double[] money;
    String[] name;

    //... init your arrays here!

    int index = getMinIndex(money);

    System.out.println("Min money = " + money[index] + "; name = " + name[index]);
}
```

However, following an object oriented approach rogues solution is much nicer!!!